# Git-receive-pack fatal

Tags: git, git-shell

I've setup a git repository behind linux ssh server. The repository is located at `/home/git/mimpi.git`. Login shell of user git is `/usr/bin/git-shell`
`pub/priv` ssh keys have been setup and tested on `client/server` side.

Now I'm trying to validate the setup, using `git-receive-pack`, but it always fails with `fatal: bad argument`.

```
kalou@client:~$ ssh git@0 git-receive-pack mimpi.git
Enter passphrase for key '/home/kalou/.ssh/id_rsa':
fatal: bad argument
```

I tried to put single quotes around mimpi.git, with no success
(https://github.com/dulwich/dulwich/issues/365)

I tried to run `strace -f sshd` to follow execution of `git-shell`, but did not find anything meaningfull after:

```
17882 execve("/usr/bin/git-shell", ["git-shell", "-c", "git-receive-pack /home/git/mimpi"...], [/* 9 vars */]) = 0
```

and before `fatal: bad argument" ...`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git-shell` does very limited unquoting. You should quote your repository only with single quotes:

```
$ ssh git@0 "git-receive-pack 'mimpi.git'"
```

I am not sure you should do it with ssh exactly like this, but at least  running git shell locally succeeds this way:

```
git shell -c "git-receive-pack '.'"
..lists references...
```